# Issue with connecting MySQL to VB.NET when multiple users

Tags: mysql, vb.net, string, connection

I'm doing a computing project in VB.NET which requires a user to login  before the application runs. I also need to use databases throughout so my weapon of choice was MySQL.

This is the code I am using for when the user presses the login button which connects and opens the database.

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;" _
        & "user id=" & txtUsername.Text & ";" _
        & "password=" & txtPassword.Text & ";" _
        & "database=main"
    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connection successful!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to the database: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is all well and fine but when I want to execute querys later (and in different forms) etc I will have to pretty much write the same code again. I thought of putting it in a seperate class and calling it when I needed but I couldn't see how it could grab the details form the text box for the connnection string. And I cant use static parameters as their could be use multiple users.

Thanks in advance,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

You can create MySqlConn as a global, that way it can be seen from anywhere in your application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Once you've connected (using the user name and password) you shouldn't need to reference the text boxes again.